# Python - Counting blank lines in a text file

Tags: python, file, lines

Let's say I have a file with the following content(every even line is blank):

> Line 1 
>  Line 2 
>  Line 3 
>  ...

I tried to read the file in 2 ways:

```
count = 0
for line in open("myfile.txt"):
   if line == '':                   #or if len(line) == 0
     count += 1
```

and

```
count = 0 
file = open('myfile.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
   if line == '':                   #or if len(line) == 0
     count += 1
```

But `count` always remains 0. How can I count the number of blank lines?

Comment: Blank lines still contain a newline character. `strip()` will remove white space, including newlines. Use `if not line.strip():`

Answer (score 3):

In a more simple and pythonic way:

```
with open(filename) as fd:
    count = sum(1 for line in fd if len(line.strip()) == 0)
```

This keep the linear complexity in time and a constant complexity in memory.
And, most of all, it get rid of the variable `count` as a manually incremented variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `readlines()` function, it doesn't automatically remove the EOL characters for you. So you either compare against the end of line, something like:

```
if line == os.linesep:
    count += 1
```

(you have to import `os` module of course), or you strip the line (as suggested by @khelwood's comment on your question) and compare against `''` as you are doing.

Notice that using `os.linesep` might not necessarily work as you would expect if you are running your program on a certain OS, e.g. MacOS, but the file you are checking is from a different OS, e.g. Linux, as the line ending will be different. So to check for all cases you have to do something like:

```
if line == '\n' or line == '\r' or line == '\r\n':
    count += 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Every line ends with a newline character `'\n'`. Note that it is only one character.

An easy workaround is to check wether the line equals `'\n'`, or wether its length is **1**, not 0.

Comment: In a text file created on Windows, the line would end with `'\r\n'`, and a blank line would have length 2. Use `strip`, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use count from itertools, which returns iterator. Furthermore I used just strip instead of checking length.

```
from itertools import count

counter = count()

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line.strip():
            counter.next()

print counter.next()
```

Comment: Adding integers don't increase memory usage.

Comment: I think it depends on how big integer will be, right?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point : `itertools.count` use at least as much memory as a manual counter.

Comment: @aluriak agree. Edited.